# LibreOffice Writer default template (2)

Tags: system-installation, libreoffice, default

I want to thank those who responded to my request. However, the instructions provided did not work. In fact, the directions -- which I printed to follow explicitly -- did not correspond to my version of LibreOffice Writer in several places (screens or commands in the instructions are not there or in the same place in my version).

I have already made and saved my desired default file. Where do I save it ? There must be a current default file, but I don't know where it is. I need an exact location, and I'll replace the current with my desired default file. I have found, over time, that replacing the current default file with a new one usually does the trick, but I need an exact, explicit location. This works with Mac, Windows, and I hope with Ubuntu 16.04. Again, I have both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and LibreOfficer Writer Version: 5.1.4.2 installed.

On a further note, I found and downloaded a newer version: LibreOffice Writer 5.2.2.2. How does one go about installing it? There are about 15-20 folders. Are there instructions?

Answer (score 0):

In the LibreOffice menu-bar click on `Tools` and the choose `Options`. In the options-window you can see the default path to the templates-directory.
If you click the `Edit`-button you can add a path off your choice and set it as the default if you want.[image]

For installation of LO 5.2.2.2 please refer to the installation guide at https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Install/Linux